# Is FluentCassandra / Cassandra losing my data?

Tags: cassandra, fluentcassandra

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentCassandra;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
        class Program
        {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                        var session = new CassandraSession("Tester", "localhost");

                        CreateData(session);
                        SelectData(session);
                        Console.WriteLine("Done");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                }

                private static void SelectData(CassandraSession session)
                {
                        using (var db = new CassandraContext(session))
                        {
                                var users = db.GetColumnFamily("Users2");
                                var count = users.AsObjectQueryable<User>().Count();
                                Console.WriteLine("Counted: " + count.ToString());
                        }
                }

                private static void CreateData(CassandraSession session)
                {
                        var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        for (int index = 0; index < 11 * 1000; index++)
                        {
                                using (var db = new CassandraContext(session))
                                {
                                        var users = db.GetColumnFamily("Users2");
                                        dynamic user = users.CreateRecord(index);
                                        user.Name = "UserX" + index.ToString();
                                        user.Password = "PasswordX" + index.ToString();
                                        db.Attach(user);
                                        db.SaveChanges();
                                        if (index % 1000 == 0)
                                        {
                                                var taken = DateTime.UtcNow - startTime;
                                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} thousand in {1} seconds", (index / 1000) + 1, taken.TotalSeconds));
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        class User
        {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Text { get; set; }
        }
}
```

The output of this app is

```
1 thousand in 0.2760158 seconds
2 thousand in 0.8180468 seconds
3 thousand in 1.3700784 seconds
4 thousand in 1.8971085 seconds
5 thousand in 2.4091378 seconds
6 thousand in 3.0791761 seconds
7 thousand in 3.6002059 seconds
8 thousand in 4.126236 seconds
9 thousand in 4.8292762 seconds
10 thousand in 5.3513061 seconds
11 thousand in 5.8543349 seconds
Counted: 9018
Done
```

Comment: Couple things: 1) You definitely should not create a new context for every read/write; 2) What does CF stats say about your column count?  In general 11k records in 6 seconds is a very small number and will certainly not cause Cassandra to lose records. I wish I knew more about FluentCassandra to validate your code...

Comment: The purpose of creating the context for every row was to test how quickly the client+DB can deal with a single page request to update data.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way this code works, and I should know, I am the developer of FluentCassandra.

```
         using (var db = new CassandraContext(session))
         {
              var users = db.GetColumnFamily("Users2");
              var count = users.AsObjectQueryable<User>().Count();
              Console.WriteLine("Counted: " + count.ToString());
         }
```

You are using LINQ to do a count, but Count hasn't been implemented in the LINQ support yet.  Right now there isn't a great way to count records in Cassandra.  The best way is to launch a CQL statement and run

```
SELECT count(*) FROM <COLUMN FAMILY>
```

Hope this helps.  I don't know what value you are getting from that Count method, but it sure isn't anything intended.

Comment: When you say "There is no way this code works" do you mean my code is wrong, or that there is no way it CAN work because of non implemented features?